# How can I connect git-hooks with an electron app

Tags: javascript, git, electron, ipc, child-process

I am trying to create some mechanism which my electron app can get events from git-hooks,
how should it be done? with child process? dnode?

I am trying to find a solution that won't require me to install packages at my git repository (not the electron one)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching for OS-agnostic solution, here is what could be done:

1. Create a unix socket and listen it from the Electron app in some acknowledged location, like User's App folder. For example `/home/user/app/bus.sock`
2. Create a script which connects to `/home/user/app/bus.sock` and communicate with your Electron app. If the socket doesn't exists, then the script starts electron app and after this attempts to connect to the socket.
3. Run the script from git hooks.

Unix socket allows you to open network connection without listening ports (and thus without serious security flaws). And gives an ability to communicate using any transport protocol you want: HTTP, gRPC, JSON-RPC, WebSockets, etc.